# VBA, Ampersands and Loops in range names

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure how to word this well but how do for loops work in range names? what's the correct convention? E.g. I understand how the following works:

```
For i = 1 to 3
Sheets("1").Range("A1:B" & i).......
Next i
```

But if i want it to work for the the A column as well - what's the correct convention? Can't seem to find one that works

e.g. something like below

```
For i = 1 to 3
Sheets("1").Range("A" & i ":B" & i).......
Next i
```

*Clarification*

Sorry - I should be clarify my question

I'm not really looking for a loop, I just want to include a defined integer i column A

e.g.

`Sheets("1").Range("A" & i :B3")`
if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

Probably cleener to do a range resize and enter the value in a single shot:

```
i = 3
Sheets("1").Range("A1").Resize(i, 2).Value = "Test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one `&` in the line `Sheets("1").Range("A" & i ":B" & i)` after the first `i`. Please use this: `Sheets("1").Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Value = "Test"`.

------------ Old answer ------------------
If you want to loop through all cells in Range("A1:B3") you could use this:

```
For each cell in Sheets("1").Range("A1:B3")
    cell.Value = "Test"
Next cell
```

This loop will progress like this: A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should switch from `Range("A1:B2")` to `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2))`

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify in VBA one has strings which are delimited by double quote character, e.g.

```
 "hello"
 "world"
```

To join strings together one uses an ampersand, so

```
 "hello" & " " & "world"
```

Joining strings is technically known as string concatenation.

In the light of your question it is possible to join the evaluation of variables so if i = 1 then

```
 "hello" & i & "world"
```

outputs `hello1world`.

The Range method returns a range that is either a single cell `Range("A1")` or multiple cells `Range("A1:B1")`.

Simply start and end strings with double quotes and use ampersands between components of the expression so the answer for you is

`Sheets("1").Range("A" & i & ":B3")`